# PHP/Apache2 doesn't append csv files

Tags: php, apache, csv

I'm running this php script:

```
<?php
                if (file_exists("userlexicon.csv")) {
                    echo "Le fichier existe.";
                    $array = array();
                      for ($i=0; $i < count($_POST['known']) ; $i++) {
                        if ($_POST['known'][$i] == 1) {
                          array_splice($_POST['known'], $i-1, 1);
                        }}
                        for ($i=0; $i < count($_POST['known']) ; $i++) {
                          array_push($array, array($_POST['word'][$i],$_POST['known'][$i]));
                          }
                        foreach ($array as $row) {
                          echo $row[0].' '.$row[1].'<br>';
                        }
                        $fp = fopen("userlexicon.csv", "a");
                        foreach ($array as $line) {
                            $val = explode(",", $line[0].','.$line[1]);
                            fputcsv($fp, $line[0].','.$line[1]);
                          }
                        }
                else {
                    echo "Le fichier n'existe pas.";
                $array = array();
                  for ($i=0; $i < count($_POST['known']) ; $i++) {
                    if ($_POST['known'][$i] == 1) {
                      array_splice($_POST['known'], $i-1, 1);
                    }}
                    for ($i=0; $i < count($_POST['known']) ; $i++) {
                      array_push($array, array($_POST['word'][$i],$_POST['known'][$i]));
                      }
                    foreach ($array as $row) {
                      echo $row[0].' '.$row[1].'<br>';
                    }
                    $fp = fopen('userlexicon.csv', 'w');
                    foreach ($array as $line) {
                        $val = explode(",", $line[0].','.$line[1]);
                        fputcsv($fp, $val);
                        /*$output = exec('python3 /home/mica/Documents/Python/ListNumFreq.py 2>&1');
                        echo $output;*/
                    }
                  }
                  fclose($fp);
                 ?>
```

which works fine when writing a new file "userlexicon.csv" when it doesn't exist.
However when this file already exists, the script doesn't append it (0 line is added).
I don't understand why.
I've looked up on google about file/folder permission with apache. I made sure apache had all the permissions necessary to write/edit files.
How can I fix that?

Comment: What does your http servers error log file say?

Comment: I'm running LAMP on ubuntu. Also my php doesn't display errors for some reason, it just shuts everything off.

Comment: What does "for some reason" mean? Did you deactivate error logging? Don't! You need to log errors and the like from php into the http servers error log file. That actually is the default setting. You should _not_ display errors, that only causes issues with your Web GUI. You _cannot_ program php without monitoring that log file.

Comment: I think @arkascha meant your apache or nginx error log file.

Comment: @unfairhistogram The question is tagged with `apache` and what should "the http servers error log file" else refer to if not the apache http servers error log file?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. Let me clear that I run pho on a virtual host from my PC. And I don't know why it doesn't display errors. When there are syntax errors, the browser displays a page with something like http error 5000

Comment: Change line "fputcsv($fp, $line[0].','.$line[1]);" to "fputcsv($fp, $val);"

Comment: Thank you it helped